# Flagging box goes over the title bar when scrolling

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, flag-dialog

I was flagging a question when I noticed that the flagging dialog does *over* the top bar when scrolling.

Here are some screenshots.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

(Screenshots were taken from [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour) Stack Exchange site.)

It should go under the top bar, instead of over, because the top bar stays above the rest of the page.

Comment: I actually like how it goes over the top bar, although it's not the behavior I would expect.

Comment: Do you have an argument for why it should go under? I'd think regular window < toolbar < page-wide modal "popup", so this behavior makes sense to me...